# Why does this event only seem to fire on some clicks but not on others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I set up a click event to hide my contextual menus whenever i click somewhere; but I recently changed it so that it doesn't hide it in when I click a contextual menu with checkboxes in it.
here's the code for it:

```
document.observe( 'mouseup', function( event ){ 
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    if(men_con_afisat == 'da' && anulare_ascundere_men_con == ''){
        men_con_afisat = 'nu';
        if($j(event.target).attr('class').indexOf('no_hide')<0)
        {
            alert($j(event.target).attr('class'));

            ascundere_men_con();
        }       
    }   
    else if(sectiune_pagina == 'proiecte'){ 
        perioada_dezactivare_tragere();
        perioada_dezactivare_mutare();  
    }
    else{

    }   

    coordonate_cursor_x = event.clientX;
    coordonate_cursor_y = event.clientY;    
});
```

In theory it should print the class attribute of the element i'm clicking whenever the thing I click on does not have "no_hide" in its class attribute. However that doesn't happen most of the time. It only does happen after i show and hide the contextual menu I changed the function for.

Any idea about what I might be doing wrong it it?

ascundere_men_con() is the function that hides the contextual menus.

Comment: Why are you using Prototype.js **and** jQuery? Use one, and stick to it. But don't combine them.

Comment: I don't really have a choice. I started working on the website when it was about 30% done and i had prototype in it which i'm not familiar with, didn't know it doesn't like jquery. Anyway, you think that's what might be causing my problem?

Comment: Set up a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/.

Answer (score 0):

It will only do that if `men_con_afisat == 'da' && anulare_ascundere_men_con == ''`, but the code you posted do not show where these (presumably global) variables are set.

Comment: Seems that was indeed the problem. Actually the problem was that if i clicked on the menu i didn't want hidde, I set men_con_afisat to 'nu' (which is != 'da') so the whole shabang didn't work. moved the 'men_con_afisat = 'nu'' inside my jquery if and now it works properly. Thanks